# Is there a general class of equations that includes one that I just found when solving for a particular series?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem: find an expression for the total number of gifts given over the twelve days of Christmas and generally for any n consecutive days of the same pattern starting with one gift on day one.

The series that defines this is: T(n) = [n^2+n + (n-1)^2+n-1 + (n-2)^2+n-2 + … + (n-n)^2+n-n]/2

I first found an expression for the total contribution T(k,n) of any one gift over n days, where k is the ordinal number of the day that gift begins, which is also the cardinal number of that gift given each day that it's given:
T(k,n) = (n + 1)k – k2

Holding n constant, I integrated this over k from k=1 to k=n, then found the constant of integration by inspection. I got an expression that works for any n days of Christmas:
T(n) = n^3 /6 + n^2 /2 + n/3

My question is this: Is this a part of some general class of equations associated with some type of series? And, if you want to comment, why did this work?? I was totally shooting in the dark and was shocked that I got the right answer. (Note - I'm an amateur.)

Comment: up to $n,$   total gifts is binomial coefficient $n+2$ choose $3.$   Which is $\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{ 6}  $  Related sums come under the heading of "hockey stick"  rules on Pascal's triangle.

Comment: I'll look up hockey stick. thanks

Comment: I still don't fully understand why my integration process worked to get the right equation. Can anyone help with that?